# Keep the push.php file and test APNS connection using MAMP?

Tags: iphone, ios, mamp, apple-push-notifications

Am following these tutorials to enable Apple Push Notification Server to send Notifications to device.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

From this tutorial I downloaded MAMP and "created the database to store the users details" and also I have "downloaded the PushChatServer folder from the tutorial". I stored the UDID, Device Token (from APNS), Name, Code in the database. Now I want to send Push Notifications from my localhost.

I am keeping the .pem file, push.php, push-confi.php on my desktop. From the tutorial this part I don't understand:

> In the PushChatServer directory there is a push folder that contains the PHP scripts you need to send out push requests. You should put these files in a directory on the server that is not accessible from the web, in other words outside of your DocumentRoot. This is important because you don’t want visitors to your website to download your private key! (In our MAMP setup, this is already taken care of.)
>
> The most important script in the push folder is push.php. This script should be run as a background process on your server. Every few seconds it checks if there are new push notifications to be sent out. If so, it sends them to the Apple Push Notification Service.
>
> First, we need to edit the file push_config.php, which contains the configuration options for push.php. You may need to change the passphrase for the private key and possibly the database password.
>
> As with the server API, the push script can run in either development mode or production mode. In development mode, it talks to the APNS sandbox server and it uses your development SSL certificate. You should use development mode in combination with Debug builds of your app. Production mode should be used for Ad Hoc and App Store builds of your app.

Where I want to keep my Push folder in my Mac. How can I check the APNS connection?

I placed the Push folder(Which is contains the Push.php) in my directory to read from Terminal. And also I pasted the Application folder in my directory.

Tutorial said to use this command in Terminal

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/bin/php push.php development
```

But, in MAMP I have this path

```
/Users/creagx/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.17/bin/php
```

Where I need to place the Push folder and MAMP.

I kept my .pem files and push.php files in this path: `/Users/gopi/Desktop/APNSsample/push.php`
Then I have tried to connect my .pem (SSL) to APNS using Terminal app like this

```
unknownc42c032e8297:~ name$ cd /Users/creagx/Desktop/APNSsample
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample name$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.149.34.66...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C
Connection closed by foreign host.
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample name$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert NameAPNCert.pem -key NameAPNKey.pem
Enter pass phrase for NameAPNKey.pem:
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc/OU=Internet Services/CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc/OU=Internet Services/CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2549 bytes and written 2017 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 729CC0899B36143DAC78D40B2C31ECB71C81A3BD8DC5CFD6D71AC7885DD2E63DCD47096E97A1B3AF032A8D7D48BF73DA
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1336636910
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
name
closed
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample name$ php push.php
Usage: php push.php development|production
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample name$ development
-bash: development: command not found
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample name$ php push.php development
```

I have received the APNS connection status in push_development.log like this,

```
2012-05-10T13:32:34+05:30 Push script started (development mode)
2012-05-10T13:32:34+05:30 Exiting with fatal error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Users/name/Desktop/APNSsample/push.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/creagx/name/APNSsample/push.php(82): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'pushchat', 'name', Array)
#1 /Users/creagx/name/APNSsample/push.php(36): APNS_Push->__construct(Array)
#2 {main}
```

I can't understand what I did wrong? I am using the database from MAMP. I have stored the devicetoken, messages (Payload) in MAMP SQL database.

Terminal:

```
unknownc42c032e8297:~ gopi$ cd /Users/gopi/Desktop/APNSsample/
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample gopi$ php push.php
Usage: php push.php development|production
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample gopi$ php push.php development
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample gopi$
```

In my push_development.log file:

```
2012-05-10T16:08:12+05:30 Push script started (development mode)
2012-05-10T16:08:12+05:30 Exiting with fatal error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Users/gopi/Desktop/APNSsample/push.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/gopi/Desktop/APNSsample/push.php(82): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'pushchat', 'gopi', Array)
#1 /Users/gopi/Desktop/APNSsample/push.php(36): APNS_Push->__construct(Array)
#2 {main}
```

Comment: I recommend you to copy both of the files(.pem and .php) to your desktop and try to connect to the APNS,maybe you made a mistake while converting the .p12 files in terminal,try it and post your results!

Comment: @MateusNunes I have edited my question and mentioned the Terminal responses and queries. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but for now i'm at school,so,just at night i will be able to help you.But keep in mind that for test purposes you don't need MAMP now.I'll post an answer with some initial code,at night i help you more!

Comment: @MateusNunes Thank you so much for your helping mind. I post a new question after your comment. Please view this is also i post many details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530170/apns-not-connecting-the-push-php-file-using-mamp-iphone. Thanks in advance. Am waiting for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you copy both of the .pem files to the same directory(in case desktop).Paste the following codes in terminal:

' cd /Users/gopi/Desktop/APNSSample/ '

Hit enter and you should get no erros,just a new line in Terminal.Now to test the connexion,paste the following code in terminal after you pasted the other one:

' php yourphpfile.php '

Hit enter and you should get three lines of code seying that the php file were able to reach the APNS Server.If it works,you're ok,else tell me!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr.Mateus Nunes. I have tried your code in Terminal. Please see my second edit. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to what i answered?Please be more clearly with your output!

Comment: Yes i have tried your words in Terminal. This is i have tried in Terminal unknownc42c032e8297:~ gopi$ cd /Users/gopi/Desktop/APNSsample/
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample gopi$ php push.php
Usage: php push.php development|production
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample gopi$ php push.php development
unknownc42c032e8297:APNSsample gopi$. But i didn't any three line of code in Terminal. Can you please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first piece of code i gave is a addres to your folder that contains your .pem and .php files, thats the reason why i recomended you to put both file in your desktop.So assuming that your files are in desktop and your COMPUTER USER is 'gobi'(This is very important,everything must be correct).Now,again,open Terminal and paste the code: cd /Users/YOUR_COMPUTER_USER/Desktop/  After hit enter!

Comment: Yes gopi is my Mac user name. So that command is correct.If i use simplepush.php script the three line of code am getting. like connection is Ok. Thanks in advance.